# Extract Httponly, Secure, domain and path from a cookie

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to extract the Httponly, Secure, domain and path from the given cookie in python. How do I do that ???

```
import requests

target_url = "https://www.google.com/"

try:
    response1 = requests.get(target_url)
    if response1.status_code == 200:
        response2 = response1.headers['Set-Cookie']
        print(response2)

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

targets = response2.split('; ')
for target in targets:
    print(target)
```

Result

```
1P_JAR=2020-01-26-18; expires=Tue, 25-Feb-2020 18:45:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure, NID=196=vCD6Y6ltvTmjf_VRFN9SUuqEN7OEJKjEoJg4XhiBc8Xivdez5boKQ8QzcCYung7EKe58kso1333yCrqq_Wq2QXwCZPAIrwHbo1lITA8lvqRtJERF-S6t9mMVEOg_o_Jpne5oRL3vwn8ReeV8f3Exx6ScJipPsm9MlXXir1fisho; expires=Mon, 27-Jul-2020 18:45:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
1P_JAR=2020-01-26-18
expires=Tue, 25-Feb-2020 18:45:29 GMT
path=/
domain=.google.com
Secure, NID=196=vCD6Y6ltvTmjf_VRFN9SUuqEN7OEJKjEoJg4XhiBc8Xivdez5boKQ8QzcCYung7EKe58kso1333yCrqq_Wq2QXwCZPAIrwHbo1lITA8lvqRtJERF-S6t9mMVEOg_o_Jpne5oRL3vwn8ReeV8f3Exx6ScJipPsm9MlXXir1fisho
expires=Mon, 27-Jul-2020 18:45:29 GMT
path=/
domain=.google.com
HttpOnly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little string manipulation should do the trick:

```
targets = response2.split('; ')
for target in targets:    
    print(target)
```

Output:

```
1P_JAR=2020-01-26-17
expires=Tue, 25-Feb-2020 17:36:40 GMT
path=/
domain=.google.com
Secure, NID=196=dXGexcdgLL0Ndy85DQj-Yg5aySfe_th__wZRtmnu2V2alQQdl807dMDLSTeEKb2CEfGpV17fIej7uXIp6w5Nb0Npab4nrf38fQwi480iYF8DYxa-ggSN-PTXVXeGvrwKRnmDYWmfYynSvpD-C9UUiXI59baq1dsdDtwsIL-zzq0
expires=Mon, 27-Jul-2020 17:36:40 GMT
path=/
domain=.google.com
HttpOnly
```

To get only, for example, "domain" use:

```
print(targets[3])
```

If you don't know the order of cookies, you can try a dictionary:

```
cookies = dict()
for target in targets:
    if '=' in target:
        key=target.split('=')[0]
        value=target.split('=')[1]
        cookies.update({key:value})
    else:
         cookies.update({target:target})
cookies.get('domain')
```

Output:

> .google.com